# How to get the acronym from any string?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string like:

```
"  Hello Word  "
```

How do I get the acronym "HW" excluding the leading and trailing spaces?

I tried it with looping constructs. But I want to do it without using any for loops or split method.

Additional from OP in comments:
I just want to get the first letter of every word in the string, irrespective of case. If the string is " jon snow ", I want the result as "JS"

Comment: So you want to remove any character which isn't an upper-case character? Consider a regex...

Comment: No. I just want to get the first letter of every word in the string, irrespective of case. If the string is " jon snow ", I want the result as "JS"

Comment: Try this (last one maybe?) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180992/get-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string

Comment: Why no looping constructs?  Even if you use other operations without looping explicitly, those will loop (e.g. regex).

Comment: I have a feeling this is an interview question. You know, to see how resourceful the candidate is. When they come up with a loop, the interviewer says "No, no loops". Then the candidate submits a solution with a regex, and the interviewer says "No regexes either" etc.

Comment: @Ishtiaq, please update your question to include that information about wanting to get the first letter of every word **even if it's lowercase**.

Comment: `String result = x.replaceAll("[a-z ]", "").toUpperCase();`

Comment: @PedroPinheiro That is generally what acronym means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a regex, but note that regular expression processing does include an internal loop.

The following will leave only letters which are at the beginning of a word, and then convert them to upper case:

```
    String str = " hello World 18 times ";
    String result = str.replaceAll("\\B.|\\P{L}", "").toUpperCase();
```

The result here is "HWT".

It removes every character which is not on a word boundary on its left, as well as any character which is not a letter (this will take care of spaces). The result is converted to uppercase.

Comment: RealSkeptic, while your answer is correct; the solution and the means to how he framed this question are extremely esoteric. We shouldn't propagate his want of solving this with a regex that maybe 2% of engineers can understand. We should provide him with a  general, best practices approach, something which is more commonly used in the industry.

Comment: Best answer. It should be accepted.

Comment: `String result = x.replaceAll("[a-z ]", "").toUpperCase();` this also work fine

Comment: @SaviNuclear The user asked for the letters at the beginning of each word, not for the uppercase letters in the string. It's in a comment on the question.

Comment: @DevarshDesai I disagree. The question may be esoteric, but that doesn't make the question or this answer "off-topic" for Stack Overflow. It is a great answer for the constraints given in the question. Your comment may be good for the question, not for this answer.

Comment: Hey Andreas, I never said the question or this answer is off topic; I think @RealSkeptic's answer is very clever! At the same time, there is a strong divide between pragmatism and being esoteric; this question's requirements are very unusual, and as members of a community who teach, i think it would be better for the question-er to understand **why** using the split() method and a for loop is better for: code readability, communication, matainability, and why his requirements are really arbitrary (as mentioned regex itself uses a loop).

Comment: @RealSkeptic what about if we want a space in between them? if The result should be H W T..how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice to use apache lib then please visit the below link
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#initials(java.lang.String).

Before using the regex that mentioned above the go through the complexity of both options. Moreover if apache lib suits you then need not to rotate the wheel again for the same situation use apache lib.

Note: Internally/Externally every algorithm traverse the complete string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#initials%28java.lang.String%29) if you have it, otherwise, with Java 8 you can do the following without loops (although it does have a split):

```
String word = " Hello World ";
String result = Arrays.stream(word.trim().split(" "))
        .map(word -> word.charAt(0))
        .map(c -> c.toString().toUpperCase())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String [] tokens = "Hello World".split("[\\W]");
String newString = "";
for(String s:tokens){
    newString += s.charAt(0);
}
System.out.println("Acronym - " + newString);
```

New Answer without loops -

```
String[] acronym = myString.split("(?<=[\\S])[\\S]*\\s*");
```

Comment: "I want to do it without using any for loops"

Comment: Editing answer for the same

Comment: OP said not to use split() method.

Answer (score -2):

Use Java default Tokenizer method. Tokenize the string and get the character at the first index of the token.
Hope this will help

```
StringTokenizer defaultTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (defaultTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    //get first letter of a token here
    defaultTokenizer.nextToken(); // will get u next token
}
```

Comment: The documentation of the `StringTokenizer` class says: *"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code."*

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't use `for` or `split` though.

Answer (score -2):

Just try this:-

```
package com.test.servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
public class A1 {

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        String x = "Satvir Kumar Singh ";
        int c1;
          String result = x.replaceAll("[a-z ]", "").toUpperCase();
          System.out.println(result);
        /*for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            c1 = (int) x.charAt(i); 
            if(c1>=65 && c1<=96){
                System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
            }
        }*/
    }   
}
```

You can try this then.

Comment: OP mentioned in a comment that he want "first letter of every word in the string, irrespective of case".