# Regular Expression to generate acronym from any string of words using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am looking for a regular expression to generate acronym from any string. Say I have a string like "**Apple Banana Cake**" then the result is "**ABC**". Another example is "1 **Banana 2 Orange**" then the result is "**1B2O**"

I tried as given below as mentioned here - [How to get the acronym from any string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421085/how-to-get-the-acronym-from-any-string) but that does not work as expected.

```
writeDump(reReplaceNoCase('Apple Banana Carrot','[\\B.|\\P{L}]','','ALL'));
writeDump(reReplaceNoCase('Apple Banana Carrot','[\\B.|\\P]','','ALL'));
```

Comment: Try `'\B[a-zA-Z]|[^a-zA-Z]'`

Comment: I tried it but it does not work for string like this "1 Banana 2 Orange". Here result should be 1B2O.

Comment: Did you try it with a single backslash without the square brackets? `\B.|\P{L}` https://regex101.com/r/hE3YA8/1 Or use [match](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/rematch.html) with `(?<!\S)[0-9A-Z]` and join the values to a string https://regex101.com/r/44LdAk/1

Comment: Do you want to create an initialism from a string, or do you want to create an initialism from a string _with a regex_?  IE: is it significant that the solution uses a regex operation? You can just do it a split / map / join in one expression.

Comment: An example of what Adam was saying (I'm sure someone can come up with a better implementation):
function acronym(list) {return ucase(arrayToList(arrayMap(listToArray(list," "), function(item){ return Left(Trim(item),1);}),""));}

Comment: @SteveBryant that is *very* close to what I was going to suggest! (https://trycf.com/gist/34c30d2f1408feb1bee7dad048749f93/acf2021?theme=monokai)

Comment: @AdamCameron is it a Java stream like syntax. Also trying to understand , why arrayNew(1) in first place ?

Comment: It's a work around to convert `s.split("\s+")` - which returns a Java String array - to a CFML array so one can call `map` on it. `arrayNew(1).append()` will accept a Java String array as its argument. Appending that array to an empty array just results in a CFML array of strings.

Comment: @AdamCameron wondering how we can directly call java`split()` method on a coldfusion string? How is it possible? curious to know! And , `s.split()` is available from which CF version onwards ?

Comment: CFML strings *are* java.lang.Strings (since CFMX6). So unless yer running CF5, you should be fine to just do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
writeDump(reReplaceNoCase('Apple Banana Carrot','\B[a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]','','ALL'));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piec0r/1). *Details*:

- `\B[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter that is preceded with a word char
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` - any non-alphanumeric char from the ASCII set.

Comment: This does NOT work for "Test Apple2". For this string it returns TA2 instead of TA.

Comment: @to-find Then use `\B[a-zA-Z0-9]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/piec0r/2)).